# How to solve error in xamarinForm and PageNavigation

Tags: xamarin.forms

when I use Xamarin form  Navigation page get me an error and show me a dialog
[image]
and my code is here
[image]

Comment: The first image doesn't show the error. Please provide the error from the output window once the application has stopped running, and update your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit difficult to help you with these little informations.

Which is the error? It is in compile time or in runtime?

First of all, you are creating a page "in code" but using a "HomePage" class that you have created with XAML.

I think your first change should be

```
var content = new ContentPage
```

Comment: I agree with Alessandro. The error most likely lies in this HomePage. It should just be a ContentPage if you are defining the content there.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94881/navigationpage                             please see this forum